# MySQL Auto incremento número par

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, auto-incremento

Tenho um banco MySQL com um campo `id` que é `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Tem algum problema de configuração nele  pois na hora de fazer o auto incremento está saindo exatamente nesta sequência:

```
ID: 2
ID: 12
ID: 22
ID: 32
ID: 42
```

Gostaria de saber como configuro meu db para que saia normalmente: 1,2,3,4...

Comment: Olá diego, você poderia por gentileza editar a pergunta e incluir a versão do MySQL e a *engine* utilizada? Inclua também a saída da consulta `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%'`

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro verifique se está incrementando de **1** em **1** com o seguinte comando:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%'
```

se obtiver esse resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

está fazendo corretamente o processo de incremento, se o valor do `auto_increment_increment` for diferente de **1** esse é o problema e para solucionar faça:

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1; // mudará globalmente
SET @@SESSION.auto_increment_increment=1; // mudará a sessão atual se não houver reinicio
```

e repita o inicio para verificar se alterou e se está igual da figura.

**Referencia:** [Data Administrator - MySQL Auto_increment going 2 by 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/mysql-auto-increment-going-2-by-2)

Answer (score 4):

Isto é uma configuração básica, usada normalmente quando você tem DBs divididos em mais de uma máquina (para que possam ser juntados sem conflito, ou para identificação da máquina responsável por cada grupo de dados)

As duas variáveis que controlam isso são:

```
 auto_increment_offset
 sysvar_auto_increment_increment
```

Sendo que a primeira define o número inicial de referência, e a segunda o intervalo.

### auto_increment_increment

Esta opção controla o intervalo entre os incrementos. O padrão de uma instalação é esse:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Veja o que acontece ao alterar o `auto_increment_increment`:

```
mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Conferindo as variáveis:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

E inserindo os dados:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc1 VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT col FROM autoinc1;
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
|   1 |
|  11 |
|  21 |
|  31 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

O valor se iniciou em 1, que é o `auto_increment_offset`, e "salta" de 10 em 10, que é o `auto_increment_increment`.

### auto_increment_offset

O *offset* determina o ponto de partida da coluna de auto-incremento. Veja o que acontece ao alterar o valor para 5, continuando do exemplo anterior:

```
mysql> SET @@auto_increment_offset=5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

E inserindo mais alguns dados:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc1 VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Eis o resultado:

```
mysql> SELECT col FROM autoinc1;
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
|   1 |
|  11 |
|  21 |
|  31 |
|  35 |
|  45 |
|  55 |
|  65 |
+-----+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Neste caso, o que mudou foi o *offset*, ou seja, os "saltos" continuaram de 10 em 10, mas como se tivessem começado do número 5. Note que o que já estava no DB não foi alterado, apenas os dados seguintes.

### Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset